# React Redux folder structure : where are providers?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Most of the answers on React-Redux folder structure take care of separation of components (dumb) & containers (smart). It is assumed that provider is going to be the main widget component and I've mostly seen it in parent folder (under js).

js

- actions
- components
- reducers
- containers
- main.jsx (provider)

However, in case of modular applications where for e.g. there is a react widget of 3 steps (select, review & confirmation screens), each screen will have its own provider, container & components. So, how/where should we maintain three different widget.jsx providers? Should it be under "components" folder itself?

Edit : Removed store as that's not there with redux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The container should be the parent component for the three steps. The provider should be attached to the container. The individual steps - select, review, confirmation should dispatch the actions via props on the container.

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to create separate widget for each step- select, review & confirmation or is it something not recommended. Pls note that I need to move from one step to another on click of continue. Can one widget call another on click of step one or this should be done through routing?

Comment: A separate widget should be created for each step. The parent component should manage only the navigation between the widgets.

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by widget over here. Just want to make sure that I am not confusing it with components. When you say widget for each step- do you mean each step should have its own transpiled bundle.js file created? Or are you considering .jsx file as widget for each step and calling it widgets? I thought parent component can only do routing between components; how can this be done with transpiled widgets? Am I missing something here?

Comment: I was meaning react components for each step.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. One last question - Would it be correct to assume that this single widget (comprising of three steps) would have just one provider and one container with container being the parent component involved in routing of these three steps?